# Leaderboards discord js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm storing the xp in a json file for practice. How can I display the top 10 users? The first time I
would have wanted to sort but I don't know how it would be more efficient.

```
let xpAdd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 8;

  if(!xp[message.author.id]) {
    xp[message.author.id] = {
      xp:0,
      level:1
    };
  }

  let curxp = xp[message.author.id].xp;
  let curlvl = xp[message.author.id].level;
  let nxtLevel = xp[message.author.id].level * 300;

  xp[message.author.id].xp = curxp + xpAdd;

 fs.writeFile("./xp.json", JSON.stringify(xp), (error) => {
    if(error) console.log(error);
  });
```

This is the code I store

And with this I show the level of xp

```
if(!xp[message.author.id]) {
        xp[message.author.id] = {
            xp: 0,
            level:1
        };
    }

    let curxp = xp[message.author.id].xp;
    let curlvl = xp[message.author.id].level;
    let nxtLevelXp = curlvl * 300;
    let difference = nxtLevelXp - curxp;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you should convert your object to an array so that you can format it and sort it however you prefer.

```js
// sample object
// I'm going to show the top three in this example for the interest of space
const xp = {
  "ID #1": {
     level: 3,
     xp: 300,
   },
   "ID #2": {
     level: 4,
     xp: 400,
   },
   "ID #3": {
     level: 2,
     xp: 200,
   },
   "ID #4": {
     level: 1,
     xp: 100,
   },
};

// sort entries in order of exp (descending), then single out the top three
let entries = Object.entries(xp).sort(([, a], [,  b]) => b.xp > a.xp ? 1 : -1).slice(0, 3);

// map entries to the prefered format using the data in their objects
// (in your actual command, you should use `client.users.cache.get(id).tag`,
// but since I don't have access to the client object here, I'm just writing `id`
entries = entries.map(([id, { level, xp }], idx) => `${idx + 1} -  ${id} (level ${level}; ${xp} xp)`);

// join each user by a line break
console.log(entries.join('\n'));
```

---

- [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)
- [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)
- [`Array.prototype.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: ```const xp = xp[message.author.id] = {
        xp:xp[message.author.id].xp,
        level:xp[message.author.id].level
    }``` 
something like that?